# Error using multiple clauses in IF statement SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm am having difficult using an if statement with multiple clauses in SSRS.

I am using the expression:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-14 AND DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())<-1, "Yellow") OR IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-1, "Red",  "Black")
```

For which I get the error:

```
The Color expression for the textrun ‘Project_Target_Date.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.
```

I am hoping to set the color of the Target Date to display yellow if within 2 weeks of now, to display red if target date is gone past today, otherwise to display as black.

I imagine I am leaving out/overlooking something simple.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF(
  DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-14
  AND 
  DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())<-1, "Yellow",
  IIF(
   DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-1, "Red","Black"))
```

I prefer use Switch instead of nested IIFs:

```
=Switch(
  DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-14 AND
  DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())<-1,
  "Yellow",
  DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-1,
  "Red",
  true,"Black"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting your IIFs wrong.  You can use something like:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-14 AND DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())<-1, "Yellow",IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!Project_Target_Date.Value, Now())>-1, "Red",  "Black"))
```